# Perl: string manipulation - surrounding a word with a character '@'

Tags: regex, string, perl

I am trying to extract email address from a txt file. I've thought about surrounding words that contain the '@' character. Does anybody know a expression to do that?

Comment: [What have you tried so far?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: maybe you want regex? if yes, then see something like this (see inside [this module](https://metacpan.org/module/Email::Valid))

Comment: @loldop: I want a regex but thats is not what I am looking for. As you can see the description of that module: "This module determines whether an email address is well-formed, and optionally, whether a mail host exists for the domain." What I am looking for is not for check if any email es valid, what I am looking for is just for extracting email addressed from a txt file.

Comment: Just google "regex mail address"...

Comment: mpe, don't send people off to a Web search engine. Link to a Stack Overflow question with good answers instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Whenever you need some reasonably common matching problem resolve in Perl, you should always first check the `Regexp::Common` family on CPAN. In this case: [`Regexp::Common::Email::Address`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Regexp%3a%3aCommon%3a%3aEmail%3a%3aAddress). From POD Synopsys:

```
  use Regexp::Common qw[Email::Address];
  use Email::Address;

  while (<>) {
      my (@found) = /($RE{Email}{Address})/g;
      my (@addrs) = map $_->address, Email::Address->parse("@found");
      print "X-Addresses: ", join(", ", @addrs), "\n";
  }
```

Comment: Thank you for your post even is the typical question that generates more questions when you try to compilate. See my new question about that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11983041/perl-error-message-cant-locate-in-inc

Answer (score 2):

Here's a very quick and dirty regex which will match non-whitespace characters on either side of an `@`:

```
/\S+@\S+/
```

This will match **john.smith@example.com** in

> some rubbish text john.smith@example.com more rubbish text

Hope this helps.